# iOS8 の `WKWebView` では、 `UIWebView` の `keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction` に似た設定はありますか？

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, swift, ios8

iOS8 で利用できるようになった `WKWebView` を利用しています。
ページ読み込み完了時に実行される JavaScript で、
<input> 要素の入力欄にフォーカスを当ててキーボードを出したいです。

しかしデフォルトでは、ユーザーのアクションなくキーボード入力を呼び出すことは出来ないようです。

`UIWebView` であれば `keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction` プロパティに `NO` をセットすることで
ユーザーのアクションが無くても入力欄にフォーカスを当てることが可能になりましたが、
`WKWebView` には `keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction` のような設定が見当たりません。

`WKWebView で、ユーザーアクションが無い状態での入力欄へのフォーカスを許可する方法はあるのでしょうか。